# Lost disk space after execute diskutil eraseVolume in terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, mojave

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), and i upgrade it to Mojave (10.14) the day before yesterday.
After i execute the command "sudo diskutil eraseVolume apfs none disk0s8", the problem happened, i found the disk space (almost 200GB) missing. Can anybody can help me to solve this problem? Thank a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does "sudo diskutil eraseVolume apfs none disk0s8" supposed to do ?

Comment: The volume (disk0s8) is unallocted now. I just want to create a new volume in disk0, what should i do?